# List of Native trees

Tags: trees, native-conditions

I reside in Pune (India). I am trying to get a list of native trees which can be planted on a hill near our house. I tried to google the list but couldnt find one. Can somebody please help with it?
The trees can be flowering or fruit bearing.

Answer (score 5):

Not the whole list of plants, but I can suggest a few names: Neem, Chickoo, Mango, Banana will grow well.

**However a generic solution is below:**

Being in Maharashtra, India, according to average temperature here, those plants who can grow in heat greater than 12.8 Celsius. i.e. [Hardiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardiness_zone#USDA_hardiness_zones) zone **12b** can grow well in your area.

So, if you search over internet for plants having Hardiness of 12b, you can get the names of plants that can grow well in your area. 
 
You can do the reverse as well, if you know the names of plants, then before you plant it, its better to check their hardiness zone, if it matches to the your area's Hardiness zone i.e. then you can plant it.

**Note:** Plants belonging to different hardiness zone may not grow well.

Happy Gardening!

Answer (score 3):

You won't find a list because 'indiginous' or 'native' trees often weren't originally - there's been so much import/export of tree species that sometimes, trees considered native weren't really in the first place, so it depends on your definition of 'native'. These days, 'native' is usually taken to mean grown in the country for over 100 years, or longer.

There is an article in The Times of India (August 29, 2011) regarding indigenous tree planting in the Puna area, encouraging planting with financial reward for doing so, and for tending the trees, which I'd guess you already know about. In that article, they include a shortlist of the following 'indigenous' trees which might be part of the scheme: moha, mango, neem, shisha, sandalwood, anjan, suru, teak, tiwas, hurda, ain, babul, tamarind, bahida and bija. I should imagine by now there's a definite, possibly more extensive list available, if the recommendation to the Government was actually accepted and passed. Even if it wasn't, the list I've given may be of use in making your choices.

Comment: Thanks Bamboo. my idea is that the trees which grow on the hills should not mess up the local environment and also should act as refuge for local birds.

Comment: @ViSu: any of the trees on that list should be appropriate for your area then. You do need to check which of those mentioned will tolerate exposure on a hillside I guess.